# Check for working hours

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a boolean function to check whether the current date/hour is a working hours. Now knowing that working hours are from 9AM to 5PM weekly except Fridays & Saturdays, I am facing issues with what I have come up with. I think my code works well for checking for days, but I just can't get it to work with hours as well. Here is my code:

```
var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
//weekday  0==Sunday 1==Monday 2==Tuesday 3==Wednesday 4==Thurs 5==Friday 6==Sat
//Not Friday or Saturday 
if ((dayOfWeek != 5) && (dayOfWeek != 6)){

   if (now.getHours() >= 9 && now.getHours() < 17 ) {
      //Within working hours now."
   }
   else
   {
    //After working hours."
   }
}

}
```

Here is my HTML Code test on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jp9BW/
Changing my PC clock works. My test case is a working day starting 5PM. And that's when the problem happens. The else block is not hit.

Comment: The problem now is that the code I posted gets the days right. So if it is not a working Day things go right. However, the problem is when the time is out of working hours. So if it is a working day and not a working hour, the else statement is not hit.

Comment: I don't see the problem with your code. Works fine for me. Maybe you have a problem elsewhere?

Comment: Try to set the time to be Monday @7PM.. My else statement is not hit in this case. Working hours are Sundays through Thursdays 9AM-5PM

Comment: @FrengiX what does now.getHours() give for you in that case?

Comment: Monday @7PM gives me now.getHours() gives me "19"

Comment: Any ideas on this now?

Comment: well, I fail to see how 19 would not go to `else` statement, unless proven otherwise :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe, this should be enough

```
function isWorkingHour(now) {
    return now.getDay() <= 4 && now.getHours() >= 9 && now.getHours() < 17;
}
```

Comment: @FrengiX yes, it would return a boolean

Comment: @eis Hope it is okay now :)

Comment: @thefourtheye I tested it and as I am seeing that like my code, it checks properly for working days. But when it is a working day and not a working hour the elese statement is not hit.. I posted a test of this including your function on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jp9BW/2/

Test setting your PC clock to Monday at 5PM or 6PM and see.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yep this one worked..
Just had to change it to check from 9Am to 5PM instead of your version 8AM to 4PM..

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this

```
function checkOpeningTimes() {
    let date = new Date(); // current time
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let day = date.getDay();
    let openingDays = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
    return openingDays.includes( day ) && hours >= 9 && hours <= 17;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Jquery.. I am a newbie and just starting JS actually. So I can see the logic in the function but cannot relate it to my code. My idea is to create a simple boolean JS function to return true or false. In my code I will check working hours using a simple IF statement and proceed accordingly.

Comment: I really don't see the reason for adding jQuery just to check if something is in an array or not

Comment: note as well that this doesn't match the requirement. Requirement was to check if it is not friday or saturday, you're checking if it is not saturday or sunday, and checking for 09:00 - 17:30 instead of 09:00 - 17:00.

Comment: I agree @eis, I was confused here too.